# SSIS ETL Deadlock (Single Job)

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I have a single SSIS Package on the server running via SQL Agent Job. Every now an then we are getting deadlocks issue. I used Breant Ozar's sp_BlitzLock to find out the deadlocks history and got below result:

[image]

Queries:

```
    Shared Lock S: Victim
<inputbuf>
UPDATE dbo.Courses
SET
CategoryId = s.CategoryId,
Discriminator = s.Discriminator,
Type = s.Type,
ActiveStatus = s.ActiveStatus,
Name = s.Name,
IsFeatured = s.IsFeatured,
IsMandatory = s.IsMandatory,
DateAdded = s.DateAdded,
DateEdited = s.DateEdited,
IsDeleted = s.isDeleted
FROM dbo.Courses c, staging.Courses s
WHERE c.Id = s.Id   </inputbuf>


Exclusive lock X: 
<inputbuf>
    UPDATE dbo.Users
    SET
    DepartmentId = s.DepartmentId,
    IsAdmin = s.IsAdmin,
    IsLearner = s.isLearner,
    IsInstructor = s.isInstructor,
    ActiveStatus = s.activeStatus,
    DateAdded = s.DateAdded,
    DateEdited = s.DateEdited,
    IsDeleted = s.isDeleted
    FROM dbo.Users u, staging.Users s
    WHERE u.Id = s.Id
</inputbuf>
```

What I'm not understanding is although the queries are updating 2 different tables but one is causing the deadlock to the other.

System: SQL Server 2017

I wonder if someone can shed a little light on this.

Comment: Do you have any indexed views that reference both tables? I have seen that cause unexpected issues like this.

Comment: Look at the `object_names` column to see the shared object between them. Think about what aspect of the `dbo.Courses` table may directly link it to the the users table.

Comment: Could you add the entire deadlock xml  to the question and provide DDL of the tables

Comment: @RandiVertongen is it possible to share this info with you privately?

Comment: @BCM There are no indexed views at all in the database.